# Running example command for dcmqrscp in dcm4che, what file is not found?

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I tried running the example command on Mac from the command line, but it fails to run. I'm wondering what file is not found. My desktop directory does, in fact, exist. Am I missing some configuration or something?

I just downloaded all the dcm4che-5.12.0 code and sample scripts and executed the command from the example when using the --help option.

The example command is what I tried, and is shown in the attached screenshot. I'm not sure what is missing, and it's not exactly clear.

Any guidance will be appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: can you please share the whole stacktrace, if there is any ?

Comment: That is the whole stack trace, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che/tree/master/dcm4che-tool/dcm4che-tool-dcmqrscp), you have to provide a file and not a directory name to the --dicomdir option (with two "-" by the way):

```
--dicomdir <file>                   specify path to a DICOMDIR file of
                                    a DICOM File-set into which
                                    received objects are stored and
                                    from which requested objects are
                                    retrieved
```

Actually, the example from the documentation reads as follows:

```
Example: dcmqrscp -b DCMQRSCP:11112 --dicomdir /media/cdrom/DICOMDIR

=> Starts server listening on port 11112, accepting association requests
with DCMQRSCP as called AE title.
```

Comment: Bahaha! Who named that parameter? That's ridiculously hilarious. 

Where do I get a DICOMDIR file? Or can I just create an empty file and it will fill it in?

Comment: @BrianTHannan: Parameter name is quite natural IMO. In-fact, I cannot imagine other name for that parameter.

Comment: @BrianTHannan DICOMDIR is a well-known DICOM term and the name required by DICOM for a directory file that lists the (DICOM) contents on a DICOM part 10 medium. The dcmtk executable dcmgpdir can be used to create it from a directory of DICOM files.

Comment: Are you suggesting I shouldn't use the dcm4che library to create a DICOM SCP server? Should I use something like dicom4j instead?

Comment: Also, why wouldn't the error output tell me the file that is missing. It just leaves you in the dark. "A file is missing ... but I'm not going to tell you which one!" LOL ... what kind of programmer does that?

Comment: @BrianTHannan I don't want to defend the (Java) programmer for not catching the exception and not providing a more readable error message, but to me (being not familiar with this tool or library) the output is clear (a FileNotFoundException is thrown by the open() method of the DicomDirWriter class, i.e. the filename parameter specified for the --dicomdir option is invalid). However, I am familiar with the DICOM standard, so this could make the difference.

Comment: Yes, I'm very new to the standard. The mindset that it's ok to not being explicit with errors and instructions is what I like to call "The Sheldon Syndrome" where programmers are too "smart" to properly convey complex concepts to people who might not understand the domain or be on the same intelligence level. Sheldon Cooper from Big Bang Theory has this problem and that's why I've come up with the name. Sheldons are very difficult to work with and projects often fail when they are involved unless Sheldon does the entire thing on his own! Just sayin'

Comment: @BrianTHannan dcm4che is open source; you can feel free to improve it if you are unhappy with it. I am sure the development team would welcome documentation and error handling improvements from you.

Comment: I don't have time for that. I just need something that works. And my first impression is that the library doesn't work. It's not very usable. It might ultimately work, but it's certainly not something that is easily used. You have to dig and grind and grind and dig ... that's annoying, unnecessary and a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @BrianTHannan good luck; let us know if you find a better solution. Personally, I find that the more I learn about the DICOM standard, the more I am impressed with the structure and design of the DCM4CHE toolkit.

Comment: @BrianTHannan I am not suggesting, that you shouldn't use dcm4che to create a DICOM SCP, I was just pointing out to the other user, that modifiying the dcmqrscp application is not worth it, if he just needs something that has a database backend. But I have to agree, that dcm4che is not a simple library to use, documentation is almost non-existent and the whole project just seems to be a side-effect of wanting to create a Java based PACS, which dcm4chee (notice the two e-s) is. The library itself seems to be a very literal implementation of all the definitions of DICOM standard.

Comment: @BrianTHannan: I see lots of people thinking of DICOM as "just another image file format" like TIFF or JPEG. It is not. It is a complex standard bringing its own terminology and technical approaches which are backward compatible with what was en vogue in the early 90s. I am working on a DICOM toolkit which tries to abstract the API from all these details, and I can tell it is a very hard job and such a toolkit has its price. I claim you will not be able to implement a good DICOM solution with open source toolkits without becoming familiar with DICOM.

Comment: I appreciate all the comments guys, thank you very much. This should help me move forward with my solution.